# Syntax error on token "getContentPane", Identifier expected after this token

Tags: jframe

everyone. I have a GUI that doesn't seem to work for some reason, and whatever I do to try and fix this, it gets even worse. "frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);" is the only line in the code that's sending me an error, but I don't really know how to fix it. Can I get some help with this? Here is the entire GUI's code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SpellCheckerGUI {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spell Checker");
    frame.getContentPane().add(emptyLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(new JLabel("Incorrect Words"));
    frame.add(new JTextField(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't put arbitrary statements into a class declaration.

You need to put that in a constructor or `void main()`.

Answer (score 0):

Let me show you an example !!!

Use like this

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.*;

public class t1 {
    public t1(){
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spell Checker");
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Label(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setSize(800, 800);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    frame.add(new JLabel("Incorrect Words"));
    frame.add(new JTextField(100));
    }
}
```

or

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.io.*;

public class t1 {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Spell Checker");
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Label(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(new JLabel("Incorrect Words"));
        frame.add(new JTextField(100));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is:

```
emptyLabel el = new emptyLabel();
Container con = frame.getContentPane();
con.add(el, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```